# iOS copy code in clipboard not working on safari and iphone

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, iphone

Last couple of hours, i was trying to implement clipboard copy on iOS using different ways but no luck nothing is working on cross platform. I have tried different method using
     [zeorclipboard](http://zeroclipboard.org/)
     [clipboard](https://clipboardjs.com/) and 
     [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ryanpcmcquen/dx5vvzc1/utm_source=website&utm_medium=embed&utm_campaign=dx5vvzc1)

As the snap showing a code and a button below that, this is a webpage on safari browser on IPHONE and i just want to copy that code into clipboard when i press the copy code button and use that code on my APP page for verification but it is not working as i desired. With the fiddle code, when i click the button it focus on the code text-box but not select or copy that.

**N.B:** `it is working on Firefox and chrome browser but i need it on iPhone safari browser except using flash. please help me out, i am badly need it`

[image]

Comment: Hi @Being, did you get any solution of it ?